# Ajax Response Capitalizations Rules

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

A was using **DataTables** plugin, and when displaying my columns I needed to put the first letter to LowerCase for it to recognize the property/object, e.g:

```
// Object name is actually: EngineeringChange.Responsible
                    {
                        title: "Responsible",
                        data: "engineeringChange.responsible",
                        className: "columnName columnHeader",
                    },
```

I just assumed the first letter would always be capitalized to LowerCase. I tried creating a new property inside EngineeringChange named ECRNumber, so I tried:

```
                    {
                        title: "ECR Number",
                        data: "engineeringChange.eCRNumber",
                        className: "columnName columnHeader",
                    },
```

Isn't recognized as a parameter... After a bit of searching I find out the Json response I get on AJAX it's called `ecrNumber`. So now I'm actually lost on which are the rules that are automatically applied to the Json Response. How does it turn `ecr` to LowerCase and `Number` to UpperCase (the N)??

**Edit**
Sry, can´t think of any easy way to exactly reproduce my problem on a demo

**TableDesign/Creation**

```
           table = $('#tblEntries2').DataTable({
                order: [[0, 'desc']],
                deferRender: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetEntries", "AlteracaoEngenharia")',
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataSrc: '',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        onBegin();
                        $content.hide();
                        $loader.show();
                    },
                    complete: function (jsonResponse) {
                        console.log(jsonResponse);

                        onComplete();
                        $loader.hide();
                        $content.fadeIn();
                        $('#ExcelExport').show();

                        table.column(5).visible(false);
                        table.column(6).visible(false);
                        table.column(7).visible(false);
                        table.column(9).visible(false);
                        table.column(10).visible(false);
                        table.column(11).visible(false);
                    }
                },
                dom: "<'row'<'col-2'l><'col-7 text-center'B><'col-3'f>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-5'i><'col-7'p>>",
                lengthMenu: [
                    [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                    ['10', '25', '50', '100', 'Todos'],
                ],
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "Id (yr-id)",
                        data: "creationYear",
                        className: "columnNumber columnHeader",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "ECR Number",
                        data: "engineeringChange.ecrNumber",
                        className: "columnNumber columnHeader",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Criador Alteração de Engenharia",
                        data: "engineeringChange.responsible",
                        className: "columnName columnHeader",
                    },
...
```

**Handler**

```
        public IActionResult GetEntries()
        {
            GetDataEntries();

            int count = 0;
            int currentYear = 0;

            foreach (var entry in EntriesList)
            {
                EngineeringChangesListViewModel h = new EngineeringChangesListViewModel
                {
                    EngineeringChange = entry
                };

                if (currentYear != entry.DataCriacao.Year)
                {
                    count = 1;
                    currentYear = entry.DataCriacao.Year;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                }

                h.DeadLine = entry.FinishedGood.Week + " - " + entry.DataCriacao.Year.ToString();

                if (entry.OldPart == null)
                {
                    h.EngineeringChange.OldPart = new Part();
                }
                if (entry.NewPart == null)
                {
                    h.EngineeringChange.NewPart = new Part();
                }
                if (entry.FinishedGood == null)
                {
                    h.EngineeringChange.FinishedGood = new FinishedGood();
                }

                if (entry.OldPart != null && entry.OldPart.CDP.HasValue)
                    h.OldPartValue = entry.OldPart.CDP * entry.OldPart.Stock;
                if (entry.NewPart != null && entry.NewPart.CDP.HasValue)
                    h.NewPartValue = entry.NewPart.CDP * entry.NewPart.Stock;

                h.EngineeringChange.ECRNumber = entry.ECRNumber;
                //toString("D4") padds the number to always be 4 digits
                h.CreationYear = entry.DataCriacao.Year.ToString() + "_" + count.ToString("D4");
                h.IdYear = count;
                EntriesListaViewModel.Add(h);
            }


            var errorsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EntriesListaViewModel);
            Console.WriteLine(errorsJson);

            return new JsonResult(EntriesListaViewModel);
        }
```

**HANDLER OUTPUT**

```
[{"CreationYear":"2021_0001","IdYear":1,"OldPartValue":null,"NewPartValue":2061.09155,"DeadLine":"15 - 2021","EngineeringChange":{"Id":8,"DataCriacao":"2021-03-11T16:15:24.6630956","Responsible":"José António","ECRNumber":"X1232","State":"Aberto","Comment":"Teste","UserId":1,"User":null,"Component":null,"FinishedGood":{"Id":31,"Week":15,"EngineeringChangeId":8},"OldPart":{"Id":5,"Reference":"FS12848AC","Stock":null,"CDP":1.43584776,"LastExpired":null},"NewPart":{"Id":6,"Reference":"FS12848AD","Stock":1650,"CDP":1.24914646,"LastExpired":"2021-03-11T00:00:00"},"Transformation":{"Id":188,"Possible":true,"Cost":1090.0,"WillBeTransformed":true,"TransformationDate":"2021-03-13T08:48:00","Responsible":"Miguel","EngineeringChangeId":8}}},]
```

**PAGE/AJAX OUTPUT** outputs are created by `console.log()` and `Console.WriteLine()` displayed above.

ECRNumber gets named to ecrNumber...

[image]

Comment: DataTables does not apply any automated uppercase/lowercase changes to the JSON names (or values) it receives. Can you provide a [mre] showing a JSON response and a DataTables configuration which shows where this type of change is happening? You could, for example, create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), as one way of showing this.

Comment: @andrewjames Maybe I was not clear enough on the question, but the changes on capitalization occurs on the AJAX Request (Datatables is here because it's the output device I was using). If I print the JSON on my handler right before the return I have  `EngineeringChange.ECRNumber`; as soon as I get to AJAX success function it's `engineeringChange.ecrNumber`

Comment: What is the code which is making the ajax request? It's not shown in your question. In any case, this still needs a [mre], I think, so we can reliably reproduce the problem you describe (which does sound very strange, I agree - I can't imagine any ajax request tool which would cause such a change).

Comment: @andrewjames; tried to show as much info as possible on my edited question; I can't seem to think of any easy way to reproduce my problem on a demo

Comment: Thank you for the updates: Some quick notes: You have extra processing in your ajax call. You can simplify your troubleshooting by removing all of that - and just use the most basic ajax processing. Maybe, as you simplify your code, there will be a point at which your problem disappears - and then you will know what is causing the problem.

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem. For example, your JSON uses the names `EngineeringChange` and `ECRNumber`. And that is exactly what I have to use in my DataTable: `data: "EngineeringChange.ECRNumber"`.